# How to copy and save keras adabound model?

Tags: python, keras

I'm doing ML using Kfold, and I don't succeed to copy and save adabound keras model but, same code have worked fine for both adam and sgd, any help of how to copy, save, and reuse adabound model would be great.

Also, I'm using 
model1 = deepcopy(model)
than save it using 
model1.save('my_class.h5') 
and in order to predict loading it using
new_model = models.load_model('my_class.h5')

```
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    print('model',type(model))    
    model.add(Dense(250, input_dim=train_inputs.shape[1], 
activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.))
    model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opti_Bound, 
 metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(X[train], Y[train], \
            validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]), \
            epochs=2,batch_size=1000, verbose=2)
    _, train_acc = model.evaluate(X[train], Y[train], verbose=0)
    _, test_acc = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print('Train: %.3f, Test: %.3f' % (train_acc, test_acc))  
    if test_acc>=accc_tst and train_acc>=accc_trn:
        accc_tst=test_acc
        accc_trn=train_acc
        model1=deepcopy(model) 

    plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='train')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='test')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()  
    cvscores.append(test_acc * 100)  

 print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores),np.std(cvscores))) 
 model1.save('my_class.h5')
```

shortly I got this error:

```
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-4-43690e87e00a> in <module>()
     34         accc_tst=test_acc
     35         accc_trn=train_acc
---> 36         model1=deepcopy(model)
     37 
     38     # plot history

/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    178                     y = x
    179                 else:
--> 180                     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    181 
    182     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.6/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, 
state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    280             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    281         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
--> 282             y.__setstate__(state)
    283         else:
    284             if isinstance(state, tuple) and len(state) == 
2:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in 
__setstate__(self, state)
   1264 
   1265     def __setstate__(self, state):
 -> 1266         model = saving.unpickle_model(state)
   1267         self.__dict__.update(model.__dict__)
   1268 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in 
unpickle_model(state)
    433 def unpickle_model(state):
    434     f = h5dict(state, mode='r')
--> 435     return _deserialize_model(f)
    436 
    437 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in 
_deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
   297         optimizer_config = 
training_config['optimizer_config']
    298         optimizer = 
optimizers.deserialize(optimizer_config,
--> 299                                            
custom_objects=custom_objects)
    300 
    301         # Recover loss functions and metrics.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py in 
deserialize(config, custom_objects)
    766                                     
 module_objects=all_classes,
    767                                     
 custom_objects=custom_objects,
--> 768                                     
 printable_module_name='optimizer')
    769 
    770 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py 
in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, 
custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    136             if cls is None:
    137                 raise ValueError('Unknown ' + 
    printable_module_name +
--> 138                                  ': ' + class_name)
    139         if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):
    140             custom_objects = custom_objects or {}

ValueError: Unknown optimizer: AdaBound
```

I suspect, I will also get errors if I try to save and load that optimizer.
so I am actually looking for ways to copy, save and reuse\reload adabound using keras.